# Event listener for radio button deselection in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code won't work:

```
$(document).on('change', '#myRadioButton', function(){ // Won't work

});
```

I want to catch whenever a radiobutton is deselected or selected, but the code above doesn't catch when it's unselected.

What's the proper way to catch radio button deselection?

Comment: show your html please

Comment: in radio buttons there is no deselection operation... there in only a new selection which will deselect the previous one..

Comment: @Weblurk, check out my answer too plz.. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess, you should use something like that, setting onchange event on all radios from same group:

[DEMO jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wgZrL/)

```
$(document).on('change', ':radio[name=mygrp]', function(){ 
    alert($('#myRadioButton').is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Ended up using this solution. Any idea of why the 'change' event won't fire when radio is deselected? You ARE changing it's value after all.

Comment: Should see the specification but i think this is not what specification says, fire change event of radio button when deselected.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
 $('#myRadioButton').change(function(){
   alert("changed");
});
$('input[type=radio]').not('#myRadioButton').change(function(){
$('#myRadioButton').change();
});
```

What it does ?

**We know that, a radio button only gets deselected when any other radio button gets selected.**

So I basically bind a change event for `#myRadioButton` and then bind all other radio buttons except `#myRadioButton` to the change event and on it, i invoke `#myRadioButton`'s change event. like `$('#myRadioButton').change();`

Here is the [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wX6HC/)
I'm damn sure, that it will work.

Mark it as answer if it helps :)